# Modify Last Token and Join String from New Tokens

Tags: java

I have a URL string (including optional slashes, / at beginning and/or end), e.g.

```
/level1/level2/level3
```

I need to re-write the **last token** with a certain new value and quickly re-join the string, as follows:

```
/level1/level2/level3[0]
```

The usage of Java Split is necessary (rather than indexOf) because slashes are optionally allowed at beginning/end and need to be automatically discarded, which Split does.

I have this solution, but it looks ugly; is there a better way to do it? (1) Split, (2) set the last index to a new String, (3) String.join:

```
// ItemPath is a String holding the original URL
String[] itemPathTokens = itemPath.split("/");
itemPathTokens[itemPathTokens.length-1] = new String(itemPathTokens[itemPathTokens.length-1] + "[" + newIndex + "]");
String itemPathNew = String.join("/", itemPathTokens);
```

Comment: `return (s.endsWith("/") ? s.substring(0, s.length() - 1) : s) + suffix;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lastIndexOf and compare it with length, if both are same, then directly append the index, otherwise append slash + index at the end.